# Dynamic interpolation in model attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a table products which contain these attributes

```
level_1
level_2
level_3
level_4
```

My code is like

```
if @product.level_1.present?
  # do something
elsif @product.level_2.present?
  # ...
....
end
```

instead of writing if-elsif conditions I tried to write

```
[1,2,3,4].each do |i|
  if @product.level_"#{i}"
    # do something
  end
end
```

But it didnt work and I understand the reason that because a interpolation results in a string which is appended to a model attribute it will not accept. Can anybody suggest how can we do this? Or is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is something like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each do |i|
  if @product.send "level_#{i}"
    # do something
  end
end
```